# ASP.NET MVC Change View Engine in existing project - From Razor to ASPX

Tags: asp.net

There are few posts about changing ASP .NET view engine from ASPX to Razor. 
However, I have a business need where I need to change my view engine from Razor to ASPX because we are using enterprise frameworks controls that only render pages in ASPX view engine. How do I do this?

I understand that it's trivial when we are setting up the project but this is an existing project. I have tried the following in Global.asax.cs but its does not have an option to add ASPX view engine, am I missing something here?

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine()); // no ASPX view engine option?
```

Any other way we can change View Engine from Razor to ASPX for an existing project? Otherwise, I have to create a new solution using ASPX as view engine and port all the codes, super unproductive.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the [Web Forms view engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webformviewengine(v=vs.118).aspx) using:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
```

You can even have both view engines in a single project if you don't want to rewrite any existing Razor views using the Web Froms engine.